# multiple solenoid activation

Tags: solenoid

I have made some flat strip solenoids of my own.There are about 15 of them and I want to alternately switch group of 6 & 7 or group of 3 solenoids for 5 times successively.I want to know which micro-controller and electronic switches should I use to effectively control each solenoid.The solenoids work on 12v dc 1 amp current.I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: *Any* microcontroller can do this. But you'll have to learn how to use one... 1A at 12V can be switched by any 'big' MOSFET or a 'big' darlington transistor. I would suggest a TIP122. Don't forget the diode across the solenoid!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ideas: -

[image]

Both circuits use 12V and drive a solenoid that is (a) grounded or (b) commoned up to 12V.

Regarding the Micro, you can use any 5V or 3.3V device.